# Use value of formula field in conditional

Tags: formula, case

I am trying to take the value of the `ACT_Superscore__c` formula field and use it in a CASE statement in another formula field:

```
CASE( ACT_Superscore__c , 
36, 1600, 
35, 1560,
34, 1510, 
33, 1460,
32, 1420, 
0)
```

The conditional works if I replace the field with a roll-up summary or just hard-code the value. If I remove the CASE statement and only return the value of `ACT_Superscore__c` it returns the value as expected. Not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: What shows up with the formula, as listed above? 0? Could it perhaps be an Integer vs String issue, e.g, replace 36 with "36" and see if that renders properly?

Comment: What is the return type for formula field ACT_Superscore__c? Are you getting any error while you try to save the formula?

Comment: Data types are correct, have no problems saving. It's just returning 0.

Comment: Maybe try a simpler `IF` function to test a single case first? E.g. `IF(TEXT(ACT_Superscore__c)="36", 1600, 0)`. It might provide some further clues about the datatype of ACT_Superscore__c.

Comment: I had not tried converting the value to string, but unfortunately that did not work either. Still returning 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check the datatype first.

Is ACT_Superscore__c a decimal value? Doesn't it need to be rounded?

Comment: If this is the case, `FLOOR(ACT_Superscore__c)` is probably the quick fix if it's only going to have .0

Comment: `FLOOR` did it! `ACT_Superscore__c` can potentially return a decimal value, but since I had it set to `0` decimal places I assumed it would return that value everywhere, not just in the layout.